# Multilingual lightning components inside community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, translation, community-builder

We're evaluating the option to build community with community builder using custom lightning components. The main obstacle so far is the language support inside community builder.

Default language picker has only languages manually selected on site.com panel. The problem is there are only 18 main languages to choose from. Even if the user is already registered and his language is set as for example Polish, the community builder and all components inside are rendered in English (default), beause Polish is not on the list supported by this community.

Is it possible to somehow extend that list of languages on site.com? Release notes of Winter 14 state that it supports all 150 languages: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_sitecom_languages.htm

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Maciek. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You're asking about communities but referring to 2 yr old docs about SITES. Sites are public facing web pages where Lightning is not currently supported. Let's be certain you're talking "apples to apples" and not "apples to oranges".

Comment: If you're not certain what i'm talking about please take time to actually try to setup language picker in lightning community builder before writing a comment. I'm not referring to VF SITES, but site.com, which is related to lightning community builder (they share language panel).

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_vs_sites.htm&language=en_US

Comment: You may want to look at [Add Lightning Components to Any App with Lightning Out (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm) and [Create Custom Page Layout Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_layouts.htm). Yes, you can use Site builder to build Community Pages with Lighting Components, but outside of communities, support for Lightning Components is in Beta. Beware of Security Issues.